# Identify analytic function $f$ such that $\Re(f′(z))=2\Im(z)$ and $f(1+i)=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> Let $f$ be an analytic function such that $\Re (f'(z))=2y$ and $f(1+i)=2$. 
>   What can one say about the imaginary part of $f(z)$?

Options given in the book:

(1) $ -2xy $

(2) $x^2-y^2$

(3) $2xy$

(4) $y^2-x^2$

**My efforts**

Using the formula that $f'(z)=u_x +iv_x=v_y-iu_y$

So we get that $u_x=2y$ and $v_y=2y$

$u_x=2y$, so $u(x,y)=2xy + $ some function of $y$ ( say $p(y)$)

$v_y=2y$, so  $v(x,y)=y^2 +$ some function of $x$ ( say $q(x)$ )

I still have not used the condition that $f(1+i)=2$

$f(1+i)=u(1,1)+iv(1,1)$

$2= 2 + p(1)+ 1 + q(1)$.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Option (1) and (3) are incorrect. It is clear.

Comment: Hint: So far, you used the first Cauchy-Riemann equation $$u_x=v_y$$ but not the second one $$u_y=-v_x$$

Comment: Different hint (this one, slightly on the "cheating" side): Compute $\Re g(z)$ and $\Im g(z)$ for $$g(z)=z^2$$

Comment: @Did Using the first hint, I get $u_y=2x+p'(y)=-v_x=-q'(x)$.

Comment: Right, and what can you say about the function $$2x+q'(x)=-p'(y)\ ?$$

Comment: I think I got it. LHS contain terms only in variable $x$ and RHS contain the terms only in variable $y$. $q(x)=-x^2+c_1$ and $p(y)=c_2$ and We can further show that $c_1=c_2$. So option 4 is correct.

Comment: @Did Please have a look at the above comment. I forgot to @ you.

Comment: Actually, none of the options (1), (2), (3) and (4) is correct. All one can say is that $$f(z)=-iz^2+aiz+a-ai$$ for some real number $a$. Note that the proof requires no guessing, following the steps outlined in the comments above. Anyway, $$\Im f(z)=y^2-x^2+ax-a$$ hence the correct answer is $$\text{None of the above.}$$ What is the source for this (flawed) exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(x)=-2iz$. Then, if $x,y\in\mathbb R$,\begin{align}\operatorname{Re}\bigl(g(x+yi)\bigr)&=\operatorname{Re}(2y-2xi)\\&=2y\\&=\operatorname{Re}\bigl(f'(x+yi)\bigr).\end{align}Therefore,$$(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):\operatorname{Re}(f'(z)-g(z)\bigr)=0.$$So, since $f'-g$ is analytic, $f'-g$ is constant, and, more precisely, $f'-g=ik$, with $k\in\mathbb R$. So, $f'(z)=ki-2iz$, and so $f(z)=kiz-iz^2+k'$, for some $k'\in\mathbb C$. Since $f(1+i)=2$, $k'=(1-i)k$. What this means is that$$f(z)=kiz-iz^2+(1-i)k,$$or$$f(x+yi)=-ky+2xy+k+i(kx-x^2+y^2-k).$$The only possibility consistent with this is the option (4).

Comment: But this involves a clever choice of $g$ beforehand and I think I have not reached that kind of mathematical maturity yet.   But thanks for your response.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician I just chose a function $g$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(g(z))=2\operatorname{Im}z$.

Comment: Ok. I really appreciate this answer and  also want to inform you that I have not down voted the answer. Thanks again.